# Mixing JdbcTemplate and raw JDBC

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-jdbc

I am experiencing some strange behaviour which I can't easily explain. The following code runs fine:

```
    try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
         Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
        statement.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM product");

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }

    try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
         Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
         statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO product ...");

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
```

However this code causes a deadlock:

```
    jdbcTemplate.update("DELETE FROM product");

    try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
         Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
         statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO product ...");

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
```

The exception is

java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Both jdbcTemplate and dataSource are created by Spring boot and autowired

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

The statements form part of a method in a service (with the @Transactional annotation)

Can anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: Why are you even doing it like this? Just use the `JdbcTemplate` for all of your JDBC access. Problem is that each time you do `getConnection` you are using a new connection to the database which can cause deadlocks if they operate on the same connection. To fix it simply don't do it and use the `JdbcTemplate` for all your access.

Comment: I can't use JdbcTemplate for everything - we perform mysql upserts "insert on duplicate key update .." and the KeyHolder chokes on the generated ids, wheras vanilla JDBC can accomate this. I still don't understand how I would get a deadlock if I have single threaded sequential calls which take and release connections?

Comment: Can you show use the transaction borders (@transaction), which storage engine do you use?

Comment: It doesn't matter each call to getConnection by default creates a new connection unless you are wrapping the datasource in a `TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy` but I doubt you are. You can still (and should) use the `JdbcTemplate`, use a `ConnectionCallback` for that, that way you are certain you are using the same connection for all your access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use your own JDBC code that plays nice with the connections managed by Spring's transaction management you should use DataSourceUtils to obtain the connection -- see http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DataSourceUtils.html#getConnection-javax.sql.DataSource-

In your example, depending on the transaction configuration, the first statement using the JdbcTemplate might not be committed yet, so it would block the next JDBC statement from a different connection. Using the DataSourceUtils, both statements would be using the same connection.

Comment: Thanks. I am using data source utils and its working. I may use the jdbc template as M Deinum suggested but I don't think the callback pattern adds much now we Java 7 and try with resources.